# How to set 81 as default port instead of 80 in iis?

Tags: http, iis

I want to set **81** as default port in iis **instead of 80**. Here 81 will work as default port like as 80. We can easily set port number for web site in iis by **bindings** options. But here I want to set as default port number. Please help me.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Since IIS sets 80 as the default port in the system, it may be difficult to modify other ports as the default port.

Comment: HTTP protocol only uses 80 as default port, so what you want cannot be achieved.